# Fetch data from 3 three tables whichever is not null

Tags: sql, join, null

I am trying to find the available address details from three tables.

When table 1 has the address details then get it from table1

If table 1 address has null value then consider table2,

If table 2 address has null value then consider table3, else display table1 address (null)

There are foreign keys in table 1 which can be used to join table 2 and 3 but they can be null as well in which case only data from table 1 to be considered.

In my query, I am able to join the tables when the foreign keys are available but in case they are null, the query doesn’t work!

I am not sure if I can add a ‘Case’ statement to ignore the ‘Join’ conditions in case the foreign keys are null.

Can someone please assist?

[image]

My Query is below :

```
SELECT donor.donor_num,

CASE

--WHEN donor.addr1 IS NULL THEN paraddress.addr1

--WHEN paraddress.addr1 IS NULL THEN enrparaddr.addr1

WHEN donor.addr1 IS NULL THEN enrparaddr.addr1

ELSE donor.addr1

END AS Address1,

CASE

--WHEN donor.addr2 IS NULL THEN paraddress.addr2

--WHEN paraddress.addr2 IS NULL THEN enrparaddr.addr2

WHEN donor.addr2 IS NULL THEN enrparaddr.addr2

ELSE donor.addr2

END AS Address2

FROM donor

JOIN enrparaddr ON enrparaddr.par_code = donor.enrol_code

--JOIN paraddress ON paraddress.par_code = donor.par_code

WHERE donor_num = '17206'
```

Please see attached image for the three tables

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: it should display the donor_num and the address from enrparaddr table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below - using `FULL OUTER JOIN` & `coalesce()` function

```
SELECT donor.donor_num,
       coalesce(donor.addr1,paraddress.addr1,enrparaddr.addr1) AS Address1,
       coalesce(donor.addr2,paraddress.addr2,enrparaddr.addr2) AS Address2
FROM donor
FULL OUTER JOIN enrparaddr ON enrparaddr.par_code = donor.enrol_code
FULL OUTER JOIN paraddress ON paraddress.par_code = donor.par_code
WHERE donor_num = '17206'
```

Comment: Hi fa06., thanks but this doesn't work. Possibly because the record in donor table doesn't have a par_code. Would be helpful if you can point out how to ignore the null foreign keys.

Comment: Thats brilliant..!! Appreciate your help... Have a nice weekend... :)

Comment: `FULL OUTER JOIN` is utterly not needed for this.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT donor.donor_num,CASE WHEN donor.addr1 IS NULL 
                            THEN enrparaddr.addr1
                            ELSE donor.addr1
                        END AS Address1,
                        CASE WHEN donor.addr2 IS NULL 
                             THEN enrparaddr.addr2
                             ELSE donor.addr2
                        END AS Address2

FROM donor
left join  enrparaddr ON enrparaddr.par_code = donor.enrol_code
WHERE donor_num = '17206'
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend:

```
SELECT d.donor_num,
       coalesce(d.addr1, pp.addr1, epe.addr1) AS Address1,
       coalesce(d.addr2, pp.addr2, epe.addr2) AS Address2
FROM donor d LEFT JOIN
     paraddress pp
     ON pp.par_code = d.par_code LEFT JOIN
     enrparaddr epe
     ON epe.par_code = d.enrol_code AND
        pp.par_code IS NULL
WHERE d.donor_num = 17206  -- do not use single quotes for numbers
```

Notes:

- You want a `LEFT JOIN` because you want all rows in `donors`.
- You should be joining the tables in the order used for the `COALESCE()`.
- The second `JOIN` condition can be limited to cases where the first does not match.
- Number constants should not use single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with simple Case .. When Statement:

```
Select Case     
When A.ID is NULL And B.ID is NULL And C.ID is NULL Then -- when all columns contain null
    NULL
When A.ID is NULL And B.ID is NULL Then
    C.ID
When B.ID is NULL and C.ID is NULL Then
    A.ID
When A.ID is NULL And C.ID is NULL Then
    B.ID
End As ID
From A, B, C
```